# Git branching for agile development

Tags: git, branch, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

First, I want to

1. Keep my `master` branch ALWAYS green.
2. Be able to cherry pick changes for the next release.

Branching strategy:

1. I have a `master` branch and an `integration` branch running alongside with it.
2. Branch off from `master` by tasks/issues.
3. When a task-branch finished its work, merge that into `integration` to see if it has broken any works from other task-branches. If yes, fix them.
4. Pull request from the **task-branch**(not `integration` branch) to `master` branch.

   *That means the `integration` branch is only for CI purpose, it will NEVER be merged into `master`*
5. Decide which changes the next release will include. Merge those branches into `master`.
6. Release.

Here is the problem, let's say I have the following situation:

```
master       -*-----------------
              |\
integration  -+-\-------C---F---
              |  \     /   /
ken/task#1    |   A---B   /
              |          /
bob/task#2    D---------E
```

In `F`, two things happen:

1. A merge conflict occurs as `C` and `F` have changed the same lines of `some-code.js`
2. `F` breaks some tests from `C`.

Now, Bob has to fix that, he has 2 options:

**Option 1**

1. Merge `integration` into `bob/task#2` as `G`
2. Fix the bugs in `H`
3. Merge into `integration` as `I`
4. `integration` green
5. Pull request

   ```
   master       -*--------------------------
                 |\
   integration  -+-\-------C---F-----------I
                 |  \     /   / \         /
   ken/task#1    |   A---B   /   \       /
                 |          /     \     /
   bob/task#2    D---------E-------G---H
   ```

However, with this approach, I cannot pick only `task#2` to be included in my next release. 
Because `bob/task#2`(`H`) already contains the changes made in `ken/task#1` , merging `bob/task#2` into `master` means merging `ken/task#1` into `master` together.

**Option 2**

1. Switch back to `bob/task#2`
2. Try to fix the bug in `G`
3. Merge into `integration` and run the tests to see if the tests are green
4. If it doesn't, switch back to `bob/task#2`
5. Try to fix it in `I`
6. Merge into `integration` and run the test

   ...

   Until `integration` is green.
7. Pull request

   ```
   master       -*-----------------
                 |\
   integration  -+-\-------C---F---H---J--- ..........
                 |  \     /   /   /   /
   ken/task#1    |   A---B   /   /   /
                 |          /   /   /
   bob/task#2    D---------E---G---I--- ..............
   ```

This approach prevents bundling changes from `ken/test#1` into `bob/task#2`.

However, Bob now needs to "guess" what he needs to do to fix the bug. Then merge over and over again into `integration` to see if the tests are green because `G` and `I` now don't have the tests added in `C`.

He also needs to resolve that same `some-code.js` merge conflict EVERY TIME he merges his work into `integration`, which is painful and redundant.

Does Bob have a better option 3?

Thanks.

Comment: Alternative 3: If you want to fix the merge conflict now, even though you're not yet going to merge *both* ken's branch and bob's branch into master, is to pick one of the branches, create a 3rd branch from the tip of it, `ken+bob/merge-conflict-fix`, and merge the other branch into it. ie. create a new branch at the end of bob's branch and merge ken's branch into it. Then fix the merge conflict. This way you can merge one of the two branches down, without the other, and when you get to the other you simply need to merge down the merge-conflict-fix branch instead.

Comment: Alternative 4, do alternative 3, only wait with the merge-conflict-fix branch until you need it, so whichever of the two branches is decided to merge into master first, just merge it, then later when the other comes around, merge your first branch into it and fix the merge conflicts before merging down into master.

Comment: I'm not sure about your strategy itself. The fact that releases are made out of master, yet master is never subject to CI testing, would make me a bit nervous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should considering following the Git flow:

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Here are my thoughts on how you can align with Git flow development model:

1. Developers create feature/bug-fix branches and submit pull requests to merge their changes into the Integration branch.
2. The decision as to which features will make it into a release should be made ***before*** the changes are integrated into the Integration branch - not after.  Once you've merged features into an integration branch, it is destined for a release, and the order has been determined (the order that you applied the features into the integration branch).
3. When you review a  pull request, and decide that it will make it into a release, you should then review the changeset to see if it can be merged as a fast-forward merge, whether it will result in a clean merge commit, or whether there are merge conflicts.
4. If there are merge conflicts, you should advise the developer  to re-base their changes onto the tip of the Integration branch. This results in a clean commit history and a more stable integration branch because the conflict resolution occurs on a ***development*** branch and by the developer most familiar with the code-base.
5. The merge from a development branch into the Integration branch should be clean: No merge conflicts, just fast-forward merges and/or clean merge commits.  There should be no conflict resolution occurring on the Integration branch!
6. Once you're near ready to release, create a pre-release branch off of the Integration branch (this branch is a release branch that will live longer than the development branches to stabilize the release). Only fixes go into a pre-release branch.
7. When the pre-release branch is ready for production merge the pre-release branch back into the master branch (this will be a fast-forward merge) and at the same time merge the same branch into Integration.  Take this opportunity to squash the commits into a single commit so that you have a cleaner commit history on master.
8. After you've merged into the integration or master branch, clean up your branches: delete the dev branch after merging into integration; delete the pre-release branch after merging into master.
9. Tag production releases using a semantic versioning strategy.  Create an official release branch to support fixes going forward.
10. When you identify an issue on the release branch, follow the same process to fix the issue as you would for developing new features (steps 1-5). Make fixing on the master branch a priority over fixing the issue on the release branch.   Once fixed, cherry-pick the fix onto the release branch.
11. The strategy for a hot fix is different. For a hot fix, apply the fix from a branch off of master, and cherry-pick the fix onto the Integration branch.

To summarize, the main points that I would recommend is:

1. Have developers merge the code and handle merge conflicts on a development branch before they are pulled into the Integration branch
2. Pick and choose which pull requests (dev branches) will make it into a release. Once decided, the features are destined for release.
3. Do not cherry-pick commits/changes from the integration branch into master!
4. Merges into master should *always* be fast forward merges. Since you have an additional integration branch, there is no reason why you wouldn't want to enforce this.

Git Flow is well-suited for medium to large-scale projects. But I actually prefer GitHub Flow for smaller projects, especially if I'm developing component libraries for the web.

Learn more about it here:
http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html